# Change Font size depending on available font

Tags: php, html, css, fonts, font-size

Is it possible to change Font-size depending on a font available on user's device?!

I mean - I am going to use non-mainstream font - sure, I would provide fall-back fonts, but can I also give a fall-back font-size?

My font is suppossed to be thin - say

Times New Roman 1.3 em;

if not available - Georgia 1.2em;

Verdana 1em;

Comment: What do you mean by fall back font? What kind of site are you using i.e. Wordpress... What is the font you want to use?

Comment: I'm using Drupal, but it doesn't matter, just for a Paragraph in Article.... The font would be Garamond - but you can also suppose as Times New Roman - it doesn't matter...just how to get a different size..

Comment: To my knowledge the answer is "no" you can not do this at least with CSS you might be able to pull something off using javascript but what would your requirements  be? i.e. How would you tell the code its time to change font sizes? What are your parameters for changing the size

Comment: If some User doesn't have Garamond font - they should use another Font, but of smaller size, because Verdana would be too huge fonts...

Comment: Instead why not add Garamond or a google font equivalent into your site via @font-face. This would ensure the font is the same across all browsers no matter what font the user has on their computer

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment this might work better for your needs.
Google fonts: https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/EB+Garamond

or
https://fonts.google.com/?query=garamond